# How Can You Open a Folder with an application in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-13.04

How Can You Open a Folder with an application from Nautilus in Ubuntu 13.04?

See this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1178697). Is there some type of plugin I can use to get around this?